# Is println method accessor or mutator in JAVA?

Tags: java, println

In `System.out.println`, `println` is a accessor or mutator method in JAVA ?

Thank you....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it's neither. It only exists for its [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29); it is not obliged to do anything at all to the internal state of `System.out` (which is what accessors and mutators are about).

Answer (score 2):

It's not an accessor, because it doesn't return a value (it's `void`). One could argue that it's a mutator, because it modifies the state of the underlying I/O system (it has side effects), but it's not a clear-cut distinction, because is not modifying the state of the `System` class or any of its instances.

The accessor/mutator distinction generally applies to methods that return a value obtained from an object's attributes (accessors) or methods that modify those attributes (mutators), but this is not the case for `println()`, the state being modified (an output stream) lies outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Accessors are "getXXX", mutators are "setXXX".  println is neither.